# opencv change video encoding parameters

Tags: c++, opencv, video, encoding, h.264

I want to create a H.264 video out of frames generated by my program in C++. Is there a way to change the video encoding parameters for the VideoWriter object in my code, except the codec (eg. CRF) like we do in FFMpeg?
Thanks for your help

Comment: I have the same problem, I would like to edit video in OpenCV, and add some information, e.g. colorspace, color primaries. As far as I know it is impossible in opencv, currently I'm using ffmpeg-python to better integration with ffmpeg encoder.